# Form php action not working

Tags: php, html, forms, button, action

This is a form with php action

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
  die('working');

}
?>
<form id="msform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<fieldset style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1); display: block;">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="display: none; left: 50%; opacity: 0;">
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"/>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The problem is that it when I click submit button nothing happens at all.

Thanks advance.

Comment: I don't see a closing form tag

Comment: sorry just forgot it in the question but also not working yet

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Is the program not displaying the message? on 'die()' ?

Comment: Yes, not displaying the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leaving `action` empty.

```
<form id="msform" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: even your original code is working for me. is there any error you see?

Comment: I don't see any error.
Did my code show you the message "working"?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help I found my mistake it was in jqery blocking it

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})

Answer (score 0):

This form will die when you click submit as it is currently working as expected.

The input for NEXT is not set to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I clicked the input Submit not next.